# PreRequestHeaders not firing

Tags: asp.net, iis

have an asp.net website running under iis integrated pipeline mode and for some reason PreSendRequestHeaders in an httpmodule is not firing.  Any ideas?

Here is my code. The module is registered in the web.config
Imports System
Imports System.Web

Namespace Test

```
Public Class HttpHeadersCleanup
    Implements IHttpModule

    Public Sub Init(context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init

        AddHandler context.PreSendRequestHeaders, AddressOf PreSendRequestHeaders

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub PreSendRequestHeaders(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server")

    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IHttpModule.Dispose
    End Sub


End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your registered section in your config file

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web> 
  <httpModules> 
   <add type= "YourNamespace.HttpHeadersCleanup, HttpHeadersCleanup" name="HttpHeadersCleanupName" /> 
  </httpModules> 
 </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858(v=vs.71).aspx